# Apache Spark -Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable" and terminate the execution

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using Apache Spark on Windows 10 64 bit machine. I have installed Java, Python 3.6 ,spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7. 
I am using VSCode editor for PySpark codeing.

When I'm executing the Python spark code in VSCode using spark-submit, it is showing

> Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... 
>   using builtin-java classes where applicable

and is terminating the execution.

Relevant code:

```python-
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf 
if name == "main": 
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("word count").setMaster("local[2]") 
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf) 
    lines = sc.textFile("in/word_count.text") 
    words = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) 
    wordcounts = words.countByValue() 
    for word, count in wordcounts.items(): 
        print("{} : {}".format(word,count))
```

**Spark Execution Error:**

[image: Spark Execution Error]

Comment: Please add your code and exception as text instead of an image. Also, that's just a warning and would not cause termination of the program. It'd be helpful if you can add the entire code (assuming it's not too big), a [mcve].

Comment: Hi, I am getting the same waring message when executing the pyspark command from windows command prompt.

Answer (score 3):

You can safely ignore the warning as it is not the reason behind your shutdown call.  According to [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.2.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/NativeLibraries.html#Supported_Platforms):

> The native hadoop library is supported on *nix platforms only. The library does not to work with Cygwin or the Mac OS X platform.
>
> The native hadoop library is mainly used on the GNU/Linus platform and has been tested on these distributions:
>
> RHEL4/Fedora
> Ubuntu
> Gentoo
> On all the above distributions a 32/64 bit native hadoop library will work with a respective 32/64 bit jvm.

Comment: Thanks, this is reassuring. Does that apply to Windows as well?